# How can I test integration with RSpec and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, devise

I have quite some issues with testing the features of my rails application using RSpec. I have a company controller, and are using devise to make sure that you need to be logged in to access the controller.

I then have integration tests like the following:

```
describe "with valid information" do
            before do
                fill_in "company_address", with: "My special address"
                fill_in "company_name", with: "My User"
                fill_in "company_contact_email", with: "test@test.com"
                fill_in "company_contact_name", with: "Someone Hello"
            end

            it "should create a company" do
                expect { click_button submit }.to change(Company, :count).by(1)
            end     
        end
```

It, of course, fails because I don't have a user who is logged in. I have tried creating a test helper like [described](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Controllers-and-Views-tests-with-Rails-3-%28and-rspec%29) here, and it works well for controllers, but not for integration tests.

What is the best way to log a user in with Devise, prior to these tests?

Answer (score 0):

add file `devise.rb` to `rspec/support`
And here is content

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
end
```

Another way to solve your problem: [Rails integration test with the devise gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292872/rails-integration-test-with-the-devise-gem)

Comment: I have already done this, but since this is not a controller, this wont work.

Comment: this question looks similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292872/rails-integration-test-with-the-devise-gem

Comment: Thanks, I had looked at it before, but I don't want to test the signup here, just make sure the user is signed in before some of the tests.

Comment: Have you tried call devise method `sign_in(:user, @user)` inside your test?

Comment: That didn't work. But I got the question you found to work, even though the test is a bit slow. Thanks a lot. Could you update your answer and I can mark it?